# VBA help needed for if then statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA problem. I want to write a If statement where i want to say if A>=B, then 0 else B-A in a new column. and i want to repeat this till last row. Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long, r As Range

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("C1:C" & N)
    r.Formula = "=IF(A1>=B1,0,B1-A1)"
End Sub
```

[image]